# Rapsberry - Bitlocker not decrypting after windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi, bitlocker

A raspberry pi is mounting a bitlocker enabled usb stick (32GB) to play some media files from it.
This works perfectly.
Untill my client updated Windows 10 this September.
Now the bitlocker enabled (exFAT) partitions have different offsets.

I can't seem to find the right offset for bdemount to use.
Is this problem windows 10 update related? How can I retrieve the right offset for using on bdemount?

See the images below.

[usb working perfectly - offset 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt0Ma.png)

[usb no mounting with bdemount after Windows 10 update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGmwS.png)

Comment: There are some copy-paste problems with the question. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1487660/edit) it to fix.

Comment: I fixed it the copy-paste problems